# (Java) Creating multiple(26) buttons with ActionListeners without repeating code

Tags: java, loops, jbutton, jlabel

I'm creating a program with a button for each letter of the alphabet. When clicked, a word is shown in one JLabel and an image in another. The word is also stored in a list. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this without repeating a block similar to this 26 times.

```
    JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
        btnA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                lblImages.setText("");
                lblImages.setIcon(newImageIcon(image);
                lblWord.setText("Apple");
                words.add(lblWord.getText());
            }
        });
    btnA.setFocusable(false);
    panel.add(btnA);
```

Comment: Create a small class that contains the letter, word and image. Create an array of objects of that class, loop over the array. In your example, the button names don't need to be uniquely named.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by defining a reusable `ActionListener`.  To make it easier, I'm also using a "word" delegate, which will actually perform the required functionality instead of exposing a bunch of components to the `ActionListener`

## `WordActionListener`

```
public class WordActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private String word;
    private WordListener listener

    public WordActionListener(String work, WordListener listener) {
        this.word = word;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        listener.addWord(word);
    }
}
```

## `WordListener`

```
public interface WordListener {
    public void addWord(String word);
}
```

## Implementation....

Your UI, which is been used to display the content will need to implement the `WordListener` interface

```
public class ... extends ... implements WordListener {
    //...

    public void addWord(String word) {
        lblImages.setText("");
        lblImages.setIcon(newImageIcon(image);
        lblWord.setText("Apple");
        words.add(lblWord.getText());
    }
}
```

When constructing your buttons, you will need a list of words...

```
private String[] listOfWords = String[] {"Apple", ..., "Zebra"};
```

Then you can just loop over them...

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    JButton btn = new JButton(Character.toString(c));
    btn.addActionListener(new WordActionListener(listOfWords[c - 'A'], this);
    btn.setFocusable(false);
    panel.add(btn);
}
```

or some such thing

Comment: Thank you, this is a much cleaner way to do it. In regards to the images that I need to display when the buttons are clicked, is renaming the image files to "character".jpeg and using the character variable "c" in the setIcon statement what I need to do?

Comment: Well, that's up to you, but, you could define an object which help both the "word" and "image" which could be passed to `WordActionListener` and back via the `WordListener`, this way, you generate a much tighter connection between the two  and decouple the code, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Since I am creating the list or words initially, I won't need to store the words in a list like my original question states. Do I still need the interface at this point? Is there a reason I'd be unable to use the actionPerformed method to display the words and the image in their respective JLabels?